# Wood moisture meter with a multimeter

Tags: multimeter, humidity, ohmmeter

I bought some firewood, but I do not think it is dry enough. I read a few articles about 18% - 20% moisture level, and I wanted to measure it, out of curiosity.

I was about to buy an electronic consumer-level "wood moisture meter", but after reading comments by buyers, I saw these meters are not really accurate. It seemed to me it is nothing more than an ohmmeter. (Also having worked a little in measurement instrument design, I know such devices are nothing if we don't have proper calibration):

[image]

This article has a table `Resistance (Megaohm) -> Moisture` for many wood species: https://www.instructables.com/Measure-the-Moisture-Content-of-Your-Firewood-With/

**Question: do some of you have accurate measurement protocol to measure wood moisture level with a < 2 Megaohm ohmmeter?**

---

The problem will of course also be to calibrate (and to get a reference sample). Do you know a model to fit for the curve? `Resistance = f(Moisture)`. There is a curve here: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Influence-of-moisture-content-and-temperature-on-the-electrical-resistance-of-timber_fig6_271662330 with a log plot, but I'm curious about a model to fit. With a good curve-fitted model + one or two samples that has, say, 5% moisture, I could then get an estimate for other firewood pieces: "The resistance is 100 times lower", this means the moisture is probably "30-35%" (if it follows the same model / curve).
As noted in a comment, there is a "knee" in the curve.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for an answer about the Resistance = f(Moisture), here you will find the answer to your question for some wood species:

[Publication by Trätek, Rapport I 9302012](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1080039/FULLTEXT01.pdf)
Source [*Diva Portal*](http://www.diva-portal.org)

All the best,
Tino

Answer (score 1):

You will notice from the instructions on the reproduced table that the nails are to 1.25" apart, and driven to a depth of 5/16".

If your problem is to get the expected indications down to 2M (your meter limitation?), then placing the nails closer together, or driving them more deeply, or using several sets of nails in parallel, will all reduce the expected resistivity. You could use an array of nails to bring your expected measurement down, or you could splash out on a slightly better DVM with better resistance range (a second DVM always comes in handy to measure voltage and current at the same time, or to corroborate an unexpected reading!)

It should be stated that this method is not really a 'measurement', more of an indication. One of the biggest variables will be what is dissolved in the water. This is the reason for the variation due to the type of wood, different woods have different detailed biology, and so different stuff in the water.

Another large problem will be the electrochemistry round the nail. Not only is the nail material not specified, but most DVMs make a DC measurement of resistance. I would expect polarisation to quickly alter the voltage between nail and wood, upsetting the resistance measurement.

The standard laboratory method of measuring water content is to heat dry the sample to constant weight. This will give you an absolute reference for the particular type of firewood that you have bought, which you can then use to calibrate your DIY electrical moisture meter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes the problem will be to calibrate (and to get a reference sample). Do you know a model to fit for the curve? `Resistance = f(Moisture)`, there is a curve here: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Influence-of-moisture-content-and-temperature-on-the-electrical-resistance-of-timber_fig6_271662330 with a log plot, but I'm curious about a model to fit.

Comment: With a good curve-fitted model + one or two samples that has, say, 5% moisture, I could then get an estimate for other firewood pieces: "The resistance is 100 times lower", this means the moisture is probably "30-35%" (if it follows the same model / curve).

Comment: The fact that there appears to be a 'knee' in the researchgate log resistance curve at around 20%, and that is the threshhold for burning it, means that you can probably get away with a very sloppy measurement of resistance. Basically if you can measure the resistance, then it's too damp, big changes in resistivity for small changes in moisture content.

Comment: "Another large problem will be the electrochemistry round the nail" You're right @Neil_UK. According to tests, it is highly sensitive with the diameter of the nail, if you push the nail to make it touch more/less surface, etc.